# how to understand the enumerations in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a rather simple question. I was trying to understand the two different ways of defining the enumeration classes. The following is the code.

```
class AnimalEnum(Enum):
      HORSE = 1
      COW = 2
      CHICKEN = 3
      DOG = 4

AnimalEnum2 = Enum('Animal', 'HORSE COW CHICKEN DOG')



def main1():
    print(AnimalEnum.CHICKEN, "\n")
    print(repr(AnimalEnum.CHICKEN), "\n")
    print("get the name and value of some Enum members:", "\n")
    print("name:", AnimalEnum.CHICKEN.name,"\n")
    print("value:",AnimalEnum.CHICKEN.value,"\n")
    for animal in AnimalEnum:
        print('Name: {} Value: {} \n'.format(animal, animal.value))  

    for a in AnimalEnum2:
        print('Name: {} Value: {} \n'.format(a,a.value))   

    for animal in AnimalEnum:
        print("animal:", animal, "\n")
        print("type of animal:", type(animal), "\n") 

    for a in AnimalEnum2:
        print("a:", a, "\n")
        print("type of a:", type(a), "\n")  # type of a: <enum 'Animal'>     



main1()
```

I understand the output of this code. My only confusing part is, for this `AnimalEnum2 = Enum('Animal', 'HORSE COW CHICKEN DOG')`, what is exactly the difference between `AnimalEnum2` and `Animal`?

Comment: There isn't one, really. Using an `Enum` as a callable in this fashion returns a new subclass of `Enum`.

Comment: so, does this mean the design of ```AnimalEnum2 = Enum('Animal', 'HORSE COW CHICKEN DOG')``` is not clean enough?

Answer (score 0):

One of them is of type enum `Animal` another is of type enum `AnimalEnum`.

Things to know here:

1. Enum using an `auto` number scheme
2. Using the Funtional API form numbers using `auto` numbering
3. Your `AnimalEnum` enum uses manual numbering

Using Enum's [Functional API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api) has the following outcome:

```
The second argument is the source of enumeration member names. 
It can be a whitespace-separated string of names, a sequence of 
names, a sequence of 2-tuples with key/value pairs, or a mapping 
(e.g. dictionary) of names to values. The last two options 
enable assigning arbitrary values to enumerations; the others 
auto-assign increasing integers starting with 1
```

This is what you are doing in `Animal` while in `AnimalEnum` you are just explicitly naming the values associated.

As for the actual usage, they are basically equivalent in practical use as all values are equivalent

Comment: One more question, suppose I have this ```AnimalEnum2 = Enum('Animal', 'HORSE COW CHICKEN DOG')``` in my python code, and I'd like to access the enumeration ```HORSE```, then I can only access it by ```AnimalEnum2.HORSE```?, I can not use ```HORSE``` directly just like the enumeration type in Julia did?

Comment: I dont know ` the enumeration type in Julia did`, but you have to use AnimalEnum2.NAME that is how Enum works